# Can we solve $z^6 = 1$ without using De Moivre's theorem?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know how to solve $z^6 = 1$ to get the six values of $z$ by using De Moivre's theorem. But is it possible to solve it without using De Moivre's theorem?

Comment: $$z^6-1=(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+z+1)(z^2-z+1)$$

Comment: @Did: Why not put that as an answer?

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. So, it is never compulsory to use the De Moivres' theorem to find the values of z right?

Comment: @Dinesh: well, the same sort of trick already doesn't work on $z^5 - 1$...

Comment: Of course its not 'compulsory', but sometimes it'll be the easiest way (out).

Comment: @Yuan so for such problems, we must need to use De Moivres' right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "the same sort of trick already doesn't work on $z^5-1$" $$z^5-1=(z-1)\left(z^2+\tfrac12(1+\sqrt5)z+1\right)\left(z^2+\tfrac12(1-\sqrt5)z+1\right)$$

Comment: $x^n-1$ is Abelian and so can be solved by radicals. (assuming you accept $n$th roots of complex numbers.)